# Adding a route to VPN network in server LAN, Windows machine

Tags: vpn, windows-7, route

I set up an OpenVPN server in my LAN in routed mode (1 network card) and I want to connect to MyLaptop from the internet. To do so, I enabled IP forwarding on the VPN server, and added a route on MyLaptop to the VPN network, with the VPN server's address in the LAN as the gateway. Without this route, MyLaptop would reply to the wrong gateway (the internet box in my case).

MyLaptop has a dual boot : I can ping it from the internet when it runs Linux, but not when it runs Win7. So I guess there must be something wrong with the way I add the route on MyLaptop in Win7.

The VPN network is 10.74.0.0/24. In Win7, I typed, with admin permissions :

```
route add 10.74.0.0 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.73.5
```

Then, I can ping the VPN server (10.74.0.1) from MyLaptop, but I can't ping MyLaptop from the internet. So, the route works, but not in all situations. I didn't set the route as permanent (-p switch) until it's not debugged.

Any idea ?

```
+--------------+       +----------------+
| VPN server   |-------| Gateway (box)  |--<internet>--
| 192.168.73.5 |       | 192.168.73.254 |
+--------------+       +----------------+
        |
        |
+--------------+
|   MyLaptop   |
| 192.168.73.9 |
+--------------+
```

Comment: What about firewall in Windows? Have you checked that? I guess you need to allow incoming ICMPv4 traffic in firewall rules.

Comment: This network scheme is wrong from the very start.

Comment: Bangal : I'll check the firewall and report here. Drookie : thanks for your constructive comment.